# Is there a way to use integers as label in StaticText

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm making a game with `wxpython` and I want to calculate the result every time button is clicked, so I created first the result on the screen, with `StaticText`, and then when any button is clicked, I want to add `(+1)` to the result.

But my problem is that I can't use integers as a label in `StaticText`, and then I can't also use `SetLabel` to set new result.

**Example:**

```
# Error
self.answers_count_num = wx.StaticText(self.panel, pos=(645, 50), label=0)

def answers_count(self, event):
     result = int(self.answers_count_num.GetLabel()) + 1
     self.answers_count_num.SetLabel(result)
```

Is there a way to use integers in a `StaticText` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use integers as the label of a `wx.StaticText` object, you first need to convert them to strings. Like:

```py
# Error
self.answers_count_num = wx.StaticText(self.panel, pos=(645, 50), label=str(0))

def answers_count(self, event):
    result = str(int(self.answers_count_num.GetLabel()) + 1)
    self.answers_count_num.SetLabel(result)
```